# jqgrid : alignment of subgrid inside jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have implemented Jqgrid with subgrid.
Sub grid is center aligned with respect to main grid. Is it possible to make it left aligned?

Comment: Subgrid is left aligned **by default**. If you have *center* aligned subgrid then you did something in your CSS or in your code which changed the alignment. You need include details in your question which shows what you do. The demo which reproduce the problem would be the best.

Comment: I agree with Oleg. If you can't get a demo up, could you at least show an image of what's happening?